# Ubuntu 17.10 won't boot after installing amdgpu-pro driver 17.50

Tags: 17.10, amdgpu-pro

My pc won't boot after installing amdgpu-pro
Here is a picture of what I get when I boot my pc:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try failsafeX in recoverymode. Then reboot.

After that, it should take you to login screen. If you encounter a login loop. Press ctrl+alt+F3, there login using your username and password. Then run,

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

And then run

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

hold ESC or Shift to enter grub boot screen

enter recovery mode

in the options menu, pick to "root"

at this point the ubuntu will drop you to cammnd line. But before doind that it will mount a safe file system, which is useless for driver removal. we need to fix that.

once in the command promt, enter
`mount -o rw,remount /`

this will remount you file system normaly.
now you can enter

`amdgpu-pro-uninstall`